# How do I separate UI and Logic in my Android game?

Tags: android

The animation in my game is choppy and I figured out that this is because the logic from the game is blocking the onDraw() in my GameView.

However, I don't know how to separate the game operation from the GameView.

Here are the relevant parts of the class that my Activity is operating:

```
public class Maze {
  ...
    public boolean keyDown(Object obj, int key) {
    switch (state) {
    // if screen shows title page, keys describe level of expertise
    // create a maze according to the user's selected level
    case Constants.STATE_TITLE:
        if (key >= '0' && key <= '9') {
            break;
        }
        if (key >= 'a' && key <= 'f') {
            break;
        }
        break;
    // if we are currently generating a maze, recognize interrupt signal (ESCAPE key)
    // to stop generation of current maze
    case Constants.STATE_GENERATING:
        if (key == ESCAPE) {
            mazebuilder.interrupt();
            buildInterrupted();
        }
        break;
    // if user explores maze, 
    // react to input for directions and interrupt signal (ESCAPE key)  
    // react to input for displaying a map of the current path or of the overall maze (on/off toggle switch)
    // react to input to display solution (on/off toggle switch)
    // react to input to increase/reduce map scale
    case Constants.STATE_PLAY:
        switch (key) {
        case 'k': case '8':
            walk(1);
            break;
        case 'h': case '4':
            rotate(1);
            break;
        case 'l': case '6':
            rotate(-1);
            break;
        case 'j': case '2':
            walk(-1);
            break;
        case ESCAPE: case 65385:
            if (solving)
                solving = false;
            else
                state = Constants.STATE_TITLE;
            break;
        case ('w' & 0x1f): 
        { 
            setCurrentPosition(px + dx, py + dy) ;
            notifyViewerRedraw() ;
            break;
        }
        case '\t': case 'm':
            mapMode = !mapMode;         
            notifyViewerRedraw() ; 
            break;
        case 'z':
            showMaze = !showMaze;       
            notifyViewerRedraw() ; 
            break;
        case 's':
            showSolution = !showSolution;       
            notifyViewerRedraw() ;
            break;
        case ('s' & 0x1f):
            if (solving)
                solving = false;
            else {
                solving = true;
            }
        break;
        case '+': case '=':
        {
            notifyViewerIncrementMapScale() ;
            notifyViewerRedraw() ; // seems useless but it is necessary to make the screen update
            break ;
        }
        case '-':
            notifyViewerDecrementMapScale() ;
            notifyViewerRedraw() ; // seems useless but it is necessary to make the screen update
            break ;
        }
        break;
    // if we are finished, return to initial state with title screen    
    case Constants.STATE_FINISH:
        state = Constants.STATE_TITLE;
        break;
    } 
    return true;
}
```

As shown above, the `Maze` object updates its variables when the user inputs a char value. This update, such as `rotate()` or `walk()` in turn calls `onDraw()`.

Here is the `walk()` method which calls `onDraw()` in my GameView:

```
    synchronized private void walk(int dir) {
    if (!checkMove(dir))
        return;
    for (int step = 0; step != 4; step++) {
        walkStep += dir;
        gameView.updateGraphics();
    }
    walkFinish(dir);
}
```

In the `for loop`, the screen is suppose to be drawn 4 times, but only the last frame is actually drawn on the screen.

How can I convert my `Maze` such that it operates all of its logic separately. I've tried to use `Asynctask`, but since my `Maze` object updates the `GameView` each time a user inputs a char value, I get an error saying that the `View` is being called from the wrong thread.

Apologies for posting so much code. I've tried asking this question many times but unfortunately no one is helping me. If you need more code for context, please comment. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm afraid that your loop is running to fast for the gameView.updateGraphics() method. and because the updateGraphics happens in the background you are firing it 4 times before the first call has the chance to add properly. how about adding a little delay with a handler?

```
int step;

for (step = 0; step != 4; step++) 
{
    new Hanlder.postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            walkStep += dir;
            gameView.updateGraphics();
        }
    }, 100 * (step + 1));
}

new Hanlder.postDelayed(new Runnable()
{
     @Override
     public void run() 
     {
         walkFinish(dir);
     }
}, 100 * (step + 1));
```

also, dont forget to modify you dir parameter to final:

```
synchronized private void walk(final int dir)
```

Comment: Hello, after some testing this still had the same results of skipping onDraw().

Comment: Ah, I found a subtle issue. The method walkFinished() is getting the wrong values. Is there a way to make everything synchronized? Perhaps making the maze thread sleep for a specified amount of time before walkFinish() executes?

Comment: Awesome! You've fixed my headache!

Comment: lol... may i advise you to learn how to work with Handlers in android... that will save you a lot of time.. promise

Comment: Yeah, I plan to do that. The purpose of creating this game was seeing how much I needed to know haha. So handlers definitely is something I will learn.